# Asp.Net SelectList labels as a field of related class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to display a specific data field of a related class (one-to-many relationship) when the field is not a foreign key? If not, how to bypass this problem?
For example:
Class **Pigeon**

```
public class Pigeon
    {
        [Key]
        public string PigeonId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RaceForeignKey")]
        public string RaceId { get; set; }

        public Race Race { get; set; }
        public Flock Flock { get; set; }
    }
```

Class **Race**

```
    public class Race
        {
            [Key]
            public string RaceId { get; set; }

            public string RaceName { get; set; } 

            public List<Pigeon> Pigeons { get; set; }
        }
```

The controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PigeonId,PigeonName,RingNumber,BirthDate,Sex,Description,Achievements,FlockId,RaceId,MotherId,FatherId,UserProfileId")] Pigeon pigeon)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                pigeon.UserProfileId = user.Id;
                _context.Add(pigeon);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["FlockId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Flock>(), "FlockId", "FlockId", pigeon.FlockId);
            ViewData["RaceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Race>(), "RaceId", "RaceId", pigeon.RaceId);
            ViewData["UserProfileId"] = new SelectList(_context.UserProfile, "Id", "Id", pigeon.UserProfileId);
            return View(pigeon);
        }
```

The View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RaceId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="RaceId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RaceId"></select>
            </div>
```

The result is [image: here]

How to Include the **Race** class to the **Pigeon** class to display RaceName instead of RaceId in the Dropdown list?

Comment: Have you tried just `ViewData["RaceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Race>(), "RaceId", "RaceName", pigeon.RaceId);`?  According to your code.. SelectList accepts the source where you are getting the list of values, the data value field, and the data text field, and selected value.. the text field is where you want to display to the user.  As of right that field is set as `RaceId`.  [More Info on SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Ofcourse I've tried this before asking, and it makes no difference. I guess I have to include the Race class somewhere while getting the data from the context but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this overload of SelectList constructor:

> SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the
> list, the data value field, the data text field, and a selected value.

so, changing your parameter, solve your problem

```
ViewData["RaceId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Race>(), "RaceId", "RaceName", pigeon.RaceId);
```

Comment: Thanks, but changing this parameter does nothing. No difference.

Comment: if you try to hard code SelectList, have any change? `ViewData["RaceId"] = _context.Set<Race>()
                          .Select(a => new SelectListItem() {  
                                                               Value = a.RaceId.ToString(),
                                                               Text = a.RaceName,
                                                            })
                          .ToList();`

Comment: No difference still :(

Comment: @Droid4o12, I tried locally and it returned correctly just changing parameter to RaceName. Can you ensure the `_context.Set<Race>()` is returning the RaceName correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem turned out to be the GET method.
I edited POST Create() method and GET Create() method should be edited also.
Now every of your proposed solutions works.

Thanks for replies, unfortunatelly I can't vote up your replies yet.